# How to send an HTTP request and don't process the response

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

As a service, my server sometimes needs to notify clients their resource is ready for use.
For that to happen, they give me a URL as a callback and when the resource is ready I send an HTTP request to their callback URL.

What is the best way to initiate an HTTP request and don't process the response?

```
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
```

In this code for example though I ignore the response completely, the server will still call a thread to download their response (which I couldn't care less...) once it's ready.

Comment: Given that you're already doing this, what's the problem with what you have?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look for a package with the id: Microsoft.Net.Http and use the more modern HttpClient from that library.
Then it is just a question of whether to 'await' for the response or not. If you dont await then it is basically fire and forget and you achieve the wanted behaviour:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
public class HttpHelper
{

    public static async Task WaitForResponse()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await  client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://google.com"));
        }
    }

    public static async Task FireAndForget()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://google.com"));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This equal to the code I have already. Even if you don't "await" the response, it's still being processed. Sorry, but it doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: This will still download the response, wasting bandwidth if you didn't need the response at all.